# Second longest prime diagonal in the Ulam spiral?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, quadratics, class-field-theory

Given the *Ulam spiral* with center $c = 41$ and the numbers in a clockwise direction, we have,

$$\begin{array}{cccccc} 
\color{red}{61}&62&63&64&\to\\
60&\color{red}{47}&48&49&50\\
59&46&\color{red}{\small{c=\,}41}&42&51\\
58&45&44&\color{red}{43}&52\\
57&56&55&54&\color{red}{53}&\downarrow\\
\end{array}$$

The main diagonal is defined by *Euler's polynomial* $F(n) = n^2+n+41$, and yields *distinct* primes for 40 consecutive $n = 0\,\text{to}\,39$.

If we let $c = 3527$ as in this old sci.math [post](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=69702&messageID=304312#304312), we get,

$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\color{blue}{3569}&3570&3571&3572&3573&3574&\to\\ 
3568&\color{red}{3547}&3548&3549&3550&3551&3552\\
3567&3546&\color{red}{3533}&3534&3535&3536&3553\\
3566&3545&3532&\color{red}{\small{c=\,}3527}&3528&3537&3554\\
3565&3544&3531&3530&\color{red}{3529}&3538&3555\\
3564&3543&3542&3541&3540&\color{red}{3539}&3556\\
3563&3562&3561&3560&3559&3558&\color{red}{3557}&\downarrow\\
\end{array}$$

The polynomial is  $G(n) = 4n^2-2n+3527$ and is prime for 23 consecutive $n = -2\,\text{to}\,20$. Its square-free discriminant is $d = -14107$ and has *[class number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html)* $h(d) = 11$. This is the 3rd largest (in absolute value) with that $h(d)$. The blue number, $G(-3)=3569$ is not prime.

***Question***: For $F(n) = n^2+n+p$, the record is held by Euler's polynomial. For the form $G(n) = 4n^2\pm 2n+p$, is there a better one?

***P.S.*** Other polynomials such as $F(n) = 6n^2+6n+31$ are prime for $n=0\,\text{to}\,28$, but are *not* diagonals in the Ulam spiral.

Comment: The primes are arise from consecutive values of the polynomial, great. What about prime rich polynomials? I recall finding such values, don't have any idea if they set records. In any case these diagonals are evident upon inspection. That the class number h(d) = 11 is interesting!

Comment: According to the prime constellation conjecture, there should be arbitrarily large diagonal sequences. This contradicts your "For $F(n)=n^2+n+p$ the record is for $p=41$". Euler's polynomial is special because $F(n)$ is prime for $0 \le n \le \frac{1+\sqrt{(p-1)/3}}2$ if and only if $h(1-4p)=1$ if and only if $F(n)$ is prime for $0 \le n \le p-2$. Sadly, $p=41$ is the largest such prime, so it gives the most spectacular sequence (in terms of its length compared to $p$). Every other sequence fails in $O(\sqrt p)$.

Comment: I found an old piece of code that runs grids of values and reports back prime rich polynomials. So...$2753 - 810n - 36n^2 $ has 132 primes between n = -100 and n = 100. and $ 3572 - 2n + 4n^2 $ has 122 primes in the the same interval.

Comment: @mercio: The [prime constellation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeConstellation.html) does not seem to discuss primes in a _quadratic_ progression. In fact, the [k-Tuple Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html) explicitly states it implies arbitrarily long _arithmetic_ progressions of primes, but is silent on quadratic ones.

Comment: @mercio: This MO post on [prime constellation conjectures](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52700/prime-constellation-conjectures) has an answer from Green and Tao's "*Linear* Equations in Primes".

Comment: Apparently what I thought were constellations are admissible k-tuples, and constellation refer to admissible k-tuples with smallest diameter. The wikipedia and mathworld pages are not clear as to why they somehow manage to include this requirement in their statement of Hardy Littlewood's first conjecture. The mathworld pages says that the "prime pattern conjecture" (which applies to arithmetic progression, and to your question here) is a special case of the conjecture about constellations (!?). Maybe the conjectural density only works for constellations and not k-tuples ? that would be weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Updated*.) Knowing more *Mathematica* coding, I re-visited this old question. Given,

$$P(n) = 4n^2\pm2n+p\tag1$$

I searched the first $million$ primes $p$. The *complete* table of record $P(n)$ with at least $14$ consecutive $n$ in the range $n = -5 \to 60\,$ yielding primes are in the table below.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{#} & P(n)=an^2+bn+c & d = b^2-4ac & h(d) & Prime\; range\; n &Total\,(T)\\
1& 4n^2-2n+41 &\color{red}{-163} & 1&-19 \to 20& 40\\
2& 4n^2-2n+3527 &\color{blue}{-14107} & 11&-2 \to 20& 23\\
3& 4n^2+2n+21377 &\color{red}{-85507} & 22&47 \to 64& 18\\
4& 4n^2-2n+9281 &\color{red}{-37123} & 17& 0 \to 16& 17\\
5& 4n^2-2n+17 &\color{blue}{-67} & 1&-7 \to 8&16\\
6& 4n^2+2n+41201&\color{red}{-164803} & 32& 52 \to 66& 15\\
7& 4n^2+2n+12821&-51283& 21& 8 \to 21& 14\\
8& 4n^2-2n+3461 &\color{red}{-13843} & 10&34 \to 47&14\\
9& 4n^2-2n+1277 &\color{blue}{-5107} & 7&19 \to 32&14\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

If the discriminant $d$ in red, then it the *largest* $|d|$ of a [class number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) $h(d)$. If it is in blue, then is one of the $3$ largest $|d|$ of that class.

For example, using #3, if you have an Ulam spiral with center $c=21377$, then in its main diagonal there are $18$ primes in a row. It involves $d = -85507$ which is the largest $|d|$ with $h(d) = 22$.

**P.S.** Considering that the millionth prime is $p(10^6) = 15485863$,
it seems odd there are no large $p$ found within the search radius.  However, I only searched $n = -5\to 60$, so another choice of range might yield other $P(n)$.

Comment: [Related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434660/) : _On the prime-generating polynomial_ $m^2+m+234505015943235329417$.