# An interesting table of Prime Generating polynomials similar to $n^2+n+41$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratics, class-field-theory

Here is some data on quadratic prime-generating polynomials of a particular form. *Kindly look at the questions given below it.* **Note**:  The discriminant $d$ is square-free and its *[class number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ClassNumber%5BSqrt%5B398%5D%5D)* $h(d)$ is also given.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{#} & P(n)=an^2+bn+c & d = b^2-4ac & h(d) & Prime\; range &Total\,(T)\\
\hline
\text{I}.\;a = b\\
1& n^2+n+41 & \color{red}{-163}& 1&0 - 39&40\\
2& n^2+n-35953 & 143813& 1& 172- 196& 25\\
3& n^2+n-169933 & 679733& 1& 379- 403& 25\\
4& n^2+n-200743 & 802973& 1& 429- 458& 30\\
5& 2n^2+2n-23813 & 47627& 8& 89- 113& 25\\
6& 3n^2+3n-199 & 2397& 2& 0- 22& 23\\
7& 3n^2+3n-35597 & 427173& 3& 97- 124& 28\\
8& 3n^2+3n-49807 & 597693& 2& 110- 137& 28\\
9& 3n^2+3n-61169 & 734037& 2& 126- 152& 27\\
10a& 4n^2+4n-(4d'-1) & d'=227& 1& 2- 26& 25\\
10b& 4n^2+4n-(16d'-1) & d'=227& 1& 19- 39& 21\\
11& 4n^2+4n-(d-1) & d=\color{blue}{398}& 1& 0- 26& 27\\
12& 4n^2+4n-(4d-1) & d=\color{blue}{398}& 1& 1-35& \color{blue}{35}\\
13& 4n^2+4n-(16d-1) & d=\color{blue}{398}& 1& 23-53& 31\\
14& 6n^2+6n+31 & \color{red}{-177}& 4& 0-28& 29\\
15& 7n^2+7n-43 & 1253& 1& 3-26& 24\\
16& 7n^2+7n-44893 & 1257053& 3& 67-91& 25\\
17& 8n^2+8n-(\tfrac{d}{2}-2) & d=\color{blue}{398}& 1& 0-30& 31\\
18& 9n^2+9n-1147 & 4597& 3& 1-27& 27\\
19& 9n^2+9n-1801 & 7213& 1& 0-23& 24\\
20& 11n^2+11n-23993 & 1055813& 4& 34-65& 32\\
21& 12n^2+12n-12041 & 9033& 1& 25-49& 25\\
22& 16n^2+16n-8773 & 8777& 1& 5-29& 25\\
\hline
\text{II.}\;b = 0\\
1& 2n^2+29 & \color{red}{-58}& 2& 0-28& 29\\
2& 4n^2-2273 & 2273 & 1& 8- 34& 27\\
3& 4n^2-8153& 8153& 1& 32- 56& 27\\
4& 4n^2-8777& 8777& 1& 33- 60& 27\\
5& 12n^2-5419 & 16257& 5& 4- 33& 30\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

I found these by making *Mathematica* look at $P(n)=an^2\pm bn \pm p_k$ such that $P(n)$ is prime for at least $24$ *n*. My search was a bit crude so it can be improved.

***Questions***: Let $P(n)$ be of these two types and ***range restricted*** to $n \ge 0$:

1. Any other $P(n)$ with total range $T \ge 24$? (*[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html)* missed #12 which is $P(n)=4n^2+4n-1591$ with $T=35$, so I assume there are more.)
2. Is there one with $T>40$?
3. Why does the real quadratic field with [$d=398$](https://oeis.org/A050953) appear often?
4. Can a $P(n)$ have *two* prime ranges that are relatively long?

$\color{green}{Update}$:

Regarding question 4. Turns out $P(n)=4n^2+4n+397$ is prime for ranges $n=0-26$ and $n=122-137$. I also checked $P(n)=n^2+n+41$  and found that the *only* other long range is $n=219-231$.

Comment: If this somehow manages to get closed, the closing system is broken.

Comment: To me it seems that these are at least 5 questions.

Comment: [Related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434660/): _The prime-generating polynomial_ $m^2+m+234505015943235329417$.

Comment: Why delete the associated account linked to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/2010890) asked today?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ It seems someone copied my question word for word. Sigh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a significant number of polynomials of this type with $T\ge 24$ but nothing with $T>40$.

The prime $k$-tuples conjecture suggests that there should be examples with $T$ arbitrarily large since $2n^2$ and $n^2+n$ omit some residue classes for every prime. For example, for $n=0,1,\ldots,9$ the differences $n^2+n-(0^2+0)$ are $(0,2,6,12,20,30,42,56,72,90)$ which forms an admissible 10-tuple of differences for primes. So we may expect there are infinitely many sets of primes with these differences, for example there are starting at,

$$11,17,41,844427,51448361,86966771,122983031,180078317$$

(*Edit*: See [A191456](https://oeis.org/A191456).) So to generate these polynomials with $T\ge 10$ we can just look for these, e.g. $n^2+n+41$, $n^2+n+51448361$ and $n^2+n+180078317$ all work, the first and last have $T>10$. Similarly the differences for $n=0,1,\ldots,39$ form an admissible 40-tuple so there should be larger primes $q$ such that $n^2+n+q$ has $T\ge 40$, but they will be tough to find with brute force.

Here are some with $T\ge 27$. Here $\operatorname{sqfr}(d)$ is the square-free part of the discriminant.
$$
\begin{array}{|cccccc|}
\hline
 Type & P(n) & T & \operatorname{sqfr}(d) & h(d) \\
\hline
I & n^2+n-1354363 & 29 & \color{blue}{5417453} & 4 \\
I & 2(n^2+n)-177953 & 27 & 355907 & 2 \\
I & 3(n^2+n)-675299 & 34 & 8103597 & 6 \\
I & 3(n^2+n)-122957 & 30 & 1475493 & 2 \\
I & 5(n^2+n)-65063 & 27 & 1301285  & 4 \\
I & 5(n^2+n)-611903 & 27 & 12238085  & 4 \\
I & 5(n^2+n-6)\color{green}{-281837} & 27 & \color{green}{5637365}  & 2 \\
I & 9(n^2+n)-90071 & 27 & 360293 & 1 \\
I & 9(n^2+n)-867551 & 27 & 3470213 & 3 \\
I & 11(n^2+n)-258113 & 27 & 11357093 & 1 \\
I & 12(n^2+n)-236111 & 27 & 708342 & 4 \\
I & 15(n^2+n)-157147 & 27 & 9429045 & 8 \\
I & 22(n^2+n)-330271 & 28 & 7266083 & 8 \\
I & 22(n^2+n)-10273 & 28 & 226127 & 4 \\
I & 35(n^2+n)+6283 & 24 & -878395 & 92 \\
I & 38(n^2+n)-9287 & 34 & 353267 & 4 \\
I & 41(n^2+n)-33023 & 29 & \color{blue}{5417453} & 4 \\
I & 45(n^2+n)-1322611 & 29 & 26452445 & 2 \\
I & 125(n^2+n)\color{green}{-281837} & 27 & \color{green}{5637365} & 2 \\
I & 175(n^2+n)-333103 & 28 & 9328109 & 1 \\
I & 210(n^2+n) - 71899 & 29 & 15109815 & 32 \\
\hline
II & 2n^2-181 & 28 & 362 & 2 \\
II & 6n^2-140897 & 33 & 845382 & 6 \\
II & 14n^2-85093 & 28 & 1191302 & 2 \\
II & 22n^2-20051 & 27 & 441122 & 2 \\
II & 30n^2-176399 & 27 & 5291970 & 8 \\
II & 38n^2-856759 & 28 & 32556842 & 2 \\
II & 42n^2-153779 & 28 & 6458718 & 8 \\
II & 258n^2+3331 & 27 & -859398 & 240 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

$n^2+n-1354363$ also has another run of 18 primes and $14n^2-85093$ another run of 17.

As per the request in the comments, here are a few more pairs of polynomials with matching $\operatorname{sqfr}(d)$ (one is repeated from above).
$$
\begin{array}{|cccc|}
\hline
P(n) & T & \operatorname{sqfr}(d) & h(d) \\
\hline
3(n^2+n-2)-58111 & 20 & 697413 & 4 \\
3^3(n^2+n)-58111 & 20 & 697413 & 4 \\
\hline
3(n^2+n-2)-92893 & 20 & 1114797 & 2 \\
3^3(n^2+n)-92893 & 18 & 1114797 & 2 \\
\hline
3(n^2+n-2)-1070633 & 16 & 12847677 & 2 \\
3^3(n^2+n)-1070633 & 18 & 12847677 & 2 \\
\hline
5(n^2+n-6)-281837 & 27 & 5637365 & 2 \\
5^3(n^2+n)-281837 & 27 & 5637365 & 2 \\
\hline
5(n^2+n-6)-1076687 & 13 & 21534365 & 12 \\
5^3(n^2+n)-1076687 & 19 & 21534365 & 12 \\
\hline
7(n^2+n-12)-112417 & 18 & 3150077 & 1 \\
7^3(n^2+n)-112417 & 18 & 3150077 & 1 \\
\hline
7(n^2+n-12)-214519 & 18 & 6008933 & 14 \\
7^3(n^2+n)-214519 & 16 & 6008933 & 14\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: That's wonderful! Are you sure the [k-tuples conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html) and [prime constellations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeConstellation.html) apply here? They involve primes in _arithmetic progression_. Do the Hardy-Littlewood conjectures extend to primes in _quadratic progression_?

Comment: Zander, are you able to find another example of $5(n^2+n-6)-p$ and $125(n^2+n)-p$, and something new for $3(n^2+n-2)-q$ and $27(n^2+n)-q$, with a run $18<T<25$? They have the same $\text{sqfr}(d)$, pairwise.

Comment: @Tito Not great ones, but I added some in a table.

Comment: Can you look at this [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557467/) and see if you can find better polynomials?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a method to generate an infinite number of prime generating polynomials. In fact, at least one prime generating polynomial can be derived for every integer. Below is the link.

[What can we learn from prime generating polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220166/what-can-we-learn-from-prime-generating-polynomials)