# Relatives of Heegner numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, class-field-theory

It is well known that [Euler's lucky numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_numbers_of_Euler) are related to the [Heegner numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number), where

\begin{align}
&n^2+n+p\\
\end{align}

gives primes for $n=0,\dots,p-2$ if and only if its discriminant $1-4p$  equals minus a Heegner number. This is then true for $p=2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 41.$

There seems to be another group of numbers, namely $p=2, 3, 5, 7, 13,$ that gives primes for

\begin{align}
&n^2+n-p^2\\
\end{align}

for $n=1,\dots,2p-2.$

eg, $n^2+n-13^2$ for $1\leq n\leq 24$ produces

$$-167, -163, -157, -149, -139, -127, -113, -97, -79, -59, -37, \
-13,$$$$ 13, 41, 71, 103, 137, 173, 211, 251, 293, 337, 383, 431.$$

The class numbers for the discriminants are not all the same however, and I could find no reference for this finite group, though there are many sequences that begin with these primes *(Mersenne exponents, Pierpont primes, etc.).*

It could, of course be coincidental, simply an example of the law of small numbers. If not though, what links these numbers if not the class numbers of the discriminants?

Comment: There is a result saying that if $p > 0$, $n^2+n+p$ is prime for $0 \le n \le p-2$ if and only if it is prime for $0 \le n \le O(\sqrt p)$ (I don't remember the exact bound). So if a similar result holds for negative $p$, this could be a coincidence.

Comment: @mercio but in this case, $p$ is essentially a square, not a prime (so it doesn't hold for $n=0$ of course).

Comment: However do note that $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{13})}$, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{41}]$, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{71}]$, ..., $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{431}]$ are all UFDs. The same is also true of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{167}]$ (as opposed to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-167})}$), $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{163}]$, etc.

Comment: This might be unrelated, but the five totally definite rational quaternion algebras of class number 1 have discriminants $2,3,5,7,13$, so one could say these are the "quaternionic Heegner numbers" (see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150073/which-quaternion-algebras-have-class-number-one)).

Comment: @mercio Not coincidence. The OP stumbled across prime producing polynomials for _real_ quadratic fields. Kindly see second answer below.

Comment: @pregunton The discriminants are actually of form $d=4p^2+1$ for $p = 2,3,5,7,13$ so $d= +17,37,101,197,677$ and we are dealing with _real_ quadratic fields. See second answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I'm very late for this 2015 question, but better late than never. Anyway, the OP has stumbled upon a *subfamily* of discriminants of ***real quadratic fields of class number 1***.

---

**I. Prime-generating polynomials**

Consider the quadratic,

$$P(x) = ax^2+bx+c$$

Its discriminant is given by the familiar $d=b^2-4ac.\,$ Given the polynomials,

$$F(x) = x^2+x+\beta,\quad d=1-4\beta$$
$$F(m) = m^2+km-1,\quad d=k^2+4\quad$$
$$\,F(n) = n^2+n-p^2,\quad\; d=1+4p^2$$

For the first if $\beta>0$, then $\sqrt{-d},$ so is for *imaginary* quadradic fields. The last two have $\sqrt{+d},$ so are for *real* quadradic fields.

---

**II. Quadratic fields**

For *imaginary quadratic fields of class number 1*, we know there's only nine, the largest being $d=163.$

For *real quadratic fields of class number 1*, there are *infinitely* many. But they can be *divided* into families depending on a related continued fraction's period length.

---

**III. Period length 1**

There are only seven, namely $d=(2, 5, 13, 29, 53, 173, 293).$ ([OEIS link](https://oeis.org/A050950))

Its **odd** primes are all of form $d=k^2+4$ for six $k = (1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17)$.

---

**IV. Period length 3**

There are only eleven, namely $d=(\color{blue}{17}, \color{blue}{37}, 61, \color{blue}{101}, \color{blue}{197}, 317, 461, 557, \color{blue}{677}, 773, 1877).$ ([OEIS link](https://oeis.org/A050952))

The blue primes are the only ones of form $d=4p^2+1$ for five $p=(2, 3, 5, 7, 13)$ which the OP should recognize are his primes.

---

**V. Range of prime-generating formulas**

Given,

$$F(x) = x^2+x+\beta$$
$$\;F(m) = m^2+km-1$$
$$\,F(n) = n^2+n-p^2$$

They are prime in the range,

\begin{align}
\text{1st: }& \, x=0 \text{ to } (\beta-2)\\ 
\text{2nd: }& \, m=1 \text{ to } (k-2)\\ 
\text{3rd: }& \, n=1 \text{ to } (2p-2)
\end{align}

Choosing the best from each, we have,

$$\;F(x) = x^2+x+41,\qquad \text{from } m = 0\text{ to } 39.$$
$$F(m) = m^2+17m-1,\quad \text{from } m = 1\text{ to } 15.$$
$$\,F(n)\, =\, n^2+n-13^2,\quad \text{from }\, n = 1\text{ to  } 24.$$

**Conclusion**: Therefore, you are right, the last two are somewhat relatives of the Heegner numbers but in the *real* quadratic field.

---

**VI. Other relatives**

But we are not limited to monic $(a=1)$ polynomials. Other nice relatives in the *imaginary* quadratic field are,

$$F(m) = 2m^2+2m+19,\quad\text{from } m = 0\text{ to } 17.$$
$$F(n) = 6n^2+6n+29,\quad\,\text{ from }\, n = 0\text{ to } 28.$$

where the first has $d = -4\times37$ (class number 2), and the second has $d = -12\times59$ (class number 4), and so on.

Comment: A [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1032108/4781) regarding $n^2+n^2+41$ and its relatives in the imaginary and real quadratic fields.

Answer (score 4):

## A Simple Answer

> If not though, what links these numbers if not the class numbers of the discriminants?

The Occam's razor answer would be divisors of 12, then add 1. This would lead to ${2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 13}$, where notably 4 is not included in your set.

In the case of 4 a slightly different equation is used:

$$
\frac{n^2 + n - q^2}{2}
$$

e.g.: $(n^2 + n - 4^2)/2$ for $1≤n≤6$ produces

$$
{-7, -5, -2, 2, 7, 13}
$$

## A More Complicated Answer

I feel like an unspoken aspect of your question was the observation that $p^2 - 6$ with prime $p$ in ${2, 3, 5, 7, 13}$ results in:

$$
-2, 3, 19, 43, 163
$$

which are all, essentially, Heegner numbers (ignoring the sign).

The following is an observation that may be helpful:

If you find all solutions to $12/(x-1) = y$ where $y$ is in ${12,11,10,...,3,2,1}$ you get:

$$
{2, \frac{23}{11}, \frac{11}{5}, \frac{7}{3}, \frac{5}{2}, \frac{19}{7}, 3, \frac{17}{5}, 4, 5, 7, 13}
$$

which is ${2, 3, 5, 7, 13}$ with an added even number and fractional values. When you plug these same numbers into $p^2 - 6$ you get:

$$
{-2, -\frac{197}{121}, -\frac{29}{25}, -\frac{5}{9}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{67}{49}, 3, \frac{139}{25}, 10, 19, 43, 163}
$$

Notably, the prime factorization includes every Heegner number at least once. Also, four new terms appear: ${5, 29, 139, 197}$.

This is circumstantial evidence that Heegner numbers may be related.

Comment: Bonus (very speculative): `Table[Numerator[2*3^n + 1]], n=-4 to 4` results in `{83, 29, 11, 5, 3, 7, 19, 55, 163}` where `55=(43+67)/2` and `2*83` is roughly the midpoint of 139 and 197. If you interpret 55 as both 43 and 67, the only excluded Heegner numbers are 1 and 2, for the half-integers. Additionally, `pi function(5) = 3, pi function(29) = 10, NumberFieldClassNumber[sqrt(-139)] = 3, NumberFieldClassNumber[sqrt(-197)] = 10`.

Comment: Largely unrelated, but possibly of interest to some is [A276260](http://oeis.org/A276260). If you do the same trick where you interpret some terms as a midpoint, then the equation `Table[Numerator[6^n + 61 + 10*(-1)^n]], n=1 to 4` can be interpreted as `53, 61, 107, 251, 283, 1367` in some sense.