# Prime Numbers and Functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any function that gives us infinitely many distinct prime numbers? 
I know that there wouldn't be any such polynomial, but what about other functions?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ does that. Or do you want all values to be prime?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Comment: But the short answer to this question is no. There is no *reasonable* algorithm which produces distinct new primes quickly.

Comment: Obviously, I need only primes. Why would I ask?

Comment: Mathematica has Prime[n] which returns the $n^{th}$ prime.  That is a fine function.  It has a unique value for each input.

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate answer to your question is that, as of now, no. By this I mean there is no function we know of where if you enter in some number $n$, $f(n)$ would provide you with the $n^{th}$ prime number.

In fact, if we had such a function we could probably learn and solve a lot of things about the [prime counting function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html) (which you may find interesting), and by extension the [Riemann Zeta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html).

Now there are smaller results that are similar to your question, such as the polynomial 
$$
n^2 + n + 41 
$$
which generates a prime number for every $1\leq n \leq 39$, but these sorts of things would depend on what you were looking for.

Comment: well, is there function which gives distinct prime values for $1 $ to $n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @SunShine:  you are defining function as a nice formula, which is not the mathematical definition.  As I said Prime[n] in Mathematica does that.  One way to generate it is the sieve of Erastosthenes.  It does not have a compact formula (as far as we know)

Comment: @RossMillikan, Oh , Okay. These primes are way to complicated!

Comment: You might be interest in this  [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1309541/4781) about $n^2+n^2+41$ and its relatives in the real quadratic fields.

Answer (score 1):

Mathworld's article on
Prime-Generating Polynomials
is quite interesting.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Here is the first paragraph:

Legendre showed that there is no rational algebraic function which always gives primes. In 1752, Goldbach showed that no polynomial with integer coefficients can give a prime for all integer values (Nagell 1951, p. 65; Hardy and Wright 1979, pp. 18 and 22).

However, there exists a polynomial in 10 variables with integer coefficients such that the set of primes equals the set of positive values of this polynomial obtained as the variables run through all nonnegative integers, although it is really a set of Diophantine equations in disguise (Ribenboim 1991). Jones, Sato, Wada, and Wiens have also found a polynomial of degree 25 in 26 variables whose positive values are exactly the prime numbers (Flannery and Flannery 2000, p. 51).