# Prime-generating polynomials like $F(n) = 7n^2+49n+41$ of real quadratic fields with class number 1?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, class-field-theory

I just answered an old post [*Relatives of Heegner numbers?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1309541/4781) about  prime-generating polynomials of form,

$$F(n)=n^2+n-p^2$$

for $p = (2,3,5,7,13)$. It turns out that since the discriminant of $F(n)$ is $d=1+4p^2$, then they were ***real** quadratic fields with class number 1 and related continued fraction of period 3*. (In my answer, I also included *period 1*).

---

Which made me think about $d$ with continued fraction of ***period 2***. Checking Mathworld's [*Prime-Generating Polynomials*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html), we find

$$F(n) = 7n^2 - 371n + 4871,\quad d = 1253\quad$$

which is prime for $n = 0\text{ to }23$. It has composite discriminant $d=7\times179$ and a check with OEIS shows that, surprisingly, it is the *largest* $d$ for period 2 ([A050951](https://oeis.org/A050951)). We can transform this to a more aesthetic form,

$$F(n) = 7n^2+49n+41,\quad d = 1253$$

But we can make it consistent with the form for period 1 which is $F(n) = an^2+abn-1$. Choosing those with highest ranges $R=1\text{ to } m$ where $m=(8,10,12,20,24)$, we have in order,

\begin{align}
F(n) &=\; 3n^2 + 15n - 1,\quad\; d = 237\\
F(n) &= 19n^2 + 19n - 1,\quad d = 437\\
F(n) &=\; 3n^2 + 21n - 1,\quad\; d = 453\\
F(n) &= 11n^2 + 33n - 1,\quad d = 1133\\
F(n) &=\; 7n^2 + 35n - 1,\quad d = 1253
\end{align}

which are the five largest $d$ of A050951.

---

**Question:** The fourteen $d$ of A050951 are,

$$d= (3, 6, 11, 21, 38, 77, 83, 93, \color{blue}{227}, 237, 437, 453, 1133, 1253)$$

However, I'm having trouble with $d=\color{blue}{227}$ since it is prime. Anyone can suggest a nice prime-generating polynomial with it as the discriminant? (Nice = relatively small coefficients.)

Comment: "However, I'm having trouble with d=227 since it is prime." Not the only prime in the list , why should this be a problem ?

Comment: @Peter I know it is not the only prime, but I wanted the six largest $d$ which covers $d=227$. The general form I'm using is $F(n) = an^2+abn-1$. If you solve for its discriminant $d$, it has factors. So an alternate form may be needed, just like Mathworld's alternate form for $d=1253$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem is you do not actually have quadratic polynomials with integer coefficients whose discriminants are $\equiv3\bmod 4$. If you look at the integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{m}]$ for $m\in\{2,3\}\bmod 4$ ($m$ squarefree), you discover that they solve quadratic equations with discriminant $4m$ not $m$.

So in your case, aim for a discriminant of $4×227=908$. The polynomial $2n^2+34n+31$ is prime for $n\in\{0,1,2,...,13\}$, with no prime factors below $29$ for any $n$ (the latter property is inherent to the chosen discriminant $908$). The translated polynomial $2n^2+30n-1$ matches the form of the quadratic polynomials given for the larger radicands in the question and is prime for $n\in\{1,2,3,...,14\}$.

Comment: After going through my [old posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1032108/4781), I saw that back in 2014, I had come across $d=227$ before. I realized the solution was to affix an even power of $2$. So I was going to answer my own question, but I'm glad you answered first. We can do a minor translation and get a form consistent with the others,$$F(n) = 2n^2 + 18n - 1,\quad d = 4\times83\\ \; F(n) = 2n^2 + 30n - 1,\quad d=4\times227$$ which are prime from $n = 1\text{ to }8,$ and $n = 1\text{ to }14,$ respectively.

Comment: For $11$: with a discriminant of $44$ either $2n^2+10n+7$ is prime for $n=0,1$; or $2n^2+6n-1$ is prime for $n=1,2$. For $3$: with a discriminant of $12$ either $2n^2+6n+3$ is prime for $n=0,1,2$; or $2n^2+2n-1$ is prime for $n=1,2,3$. Remarkably, $3$ gives "extra" prime cases and thus a longer string than $11$.