# What is so special about $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{398})$ that it has several good prime generating polynomials?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, special-functions, class-field-theory

Going through an [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1032108/4781) of mine from 2014, I realized there was a *curiosity* that hasn't been fully explained up to now. Consider the following simple prime-generating polynomials. (*My thanks to user25406 for the simpler form*.)

$$F_1(n)=(2n+1)^2-398$$
$$F_2(n)=(2n+1)^2-4\times398$$
$$\;F_3(n)=(2n+1)^2-16\times398$$
$$\,F_4(n)=2(2n+1)^2-\tfrac12\times398$$

The discriminant (square-free) of these quadratics is $d=398.$ This is the *largest* even $d$ of **real** quadratic fields with **class number 1** and related cfrac of **period 4**. ([A050953](https://oeis.org/A050953))

Just like Euler's $F(n) = n^2+n+41=\big(n+\frac12\big)^2+\frac{163}4$, the four polynomials above are remarkably good at producing primes (counting negative values):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
F_k(n)&\text{Range of n}&\text{Total primes}\\
\hline
F_1(n)& 0\text{ to }26& 27\\
\hline
F_2(n)& 1\text{ to }35& \color{red}{35}\\
\hline
F_3(n)& 23\text{ to }53& 31\\
\hline
F_4(n)& 0\text{ to }30& 31\\
\hline
\hline
\end{array}$$

with the second almost catching up with the 40 primes of Euler's polynomial. Here is is a plot of the first three (which are just squares of *odd numbers* subtracted by $398\times4^m$),

[image: Primes 398]

For period 1 and 3, see "*[Relatives of Heegner numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1309541/4781)*"
For period 2, see "*[Prime-generating polynomials like $F(n) = 7n^2+49n+41$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4756204/4781)*"

---

**Questions:**

1. Being class number 1 probably helps, but what is it that makes  $d=398$ so special it is involved in ***four*** similar polynomials very good at producing primes within a range? (The cfrac expansion of $\sqrt{398}$ is $19;\overline{1,18,1,38},$ hence has period 4.)
2. I tested $e^{\pi\sqrt{398}}$ and is nothing remarkable. After all, the j-function $j(\tau)$ uses *complex* arguments $\tau$. So is there some special function that uses *real* arguments involving $\sqrt{398}$ such that we get a Ramanujan-type result similar to $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} \approx 640320^3$?

Comment: $4n^2 + 4n -397$ can be rewritten as $4n^2 + 4n +1 -398=(2n+1)^2 -398$. the square $(2n+1)^2$ is just $8*T_{n} + 1 = 8n(n+1)/2 + 1$.

Comment: @user25406 Thanks, I've edited the post, credited to you. Euler's polynomial also has similar alternative form $$n^2+n+41 = \Big(n+\frac12\Big)^2+\frac{163}4$$ I believe mathematical expressions should be as aesthetic as possible.

Comment: In [_Prime-Generating Polynomials_](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html), there are only _three quadratics_ with a prime range greater than Euler's $R=40$. The best one so far is the [Fung-Ruby](https://oeis.org/A050268) with $R=45$. It has a nice translated form, $$F(n)=9\Big(2n+\frac12\Big)^2-\frac{7213}4$$ prime for $n = -33\text{ to }11$. The discriminant $d=7213$ is the 2nd largest for _real_ quadratic fields with class number 1, cfrac period $\color{red}9$. In the post, $$F(n)=4\Big(n+\frac12\Big)^2-1592$$ is the best with $R=35$ for cfrac period $\color{red}4$.