# On the prime-generating polynomial $m^2+m+234505015943235329417$

Tags: prime-numbers, quadratics, computational-mathematics

In 2009, J. Waldvogel and Peter Leikauf found the remarkable Euler-like polynomial,

$$F(m)=m^2+m+234505015943235329417$$

which is prime for $m=0\to20$, but composite for $m=21$. Define,

$$F(m)=m^2+m+A$$

such that $F(m)$ is prime for $m=0\to n-1$, but composite for $m=n$. Then the *least* $\color{brown}{A>41}$ (compare to [A164926](https://oeis.org/A164926)) are,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|l|}
\hline
n&\lceil\log_{10}A\rceil&A\\
\hline
1 &2&43 \\
2 &2 &59 \\
3 &3 &107 \\
4 &3 &101 \\
5 &3 &347 \\
6 &4 &1607 \\
7 &4 &1277 \\
8 &5 &21557  \\
9 &8 &51867197 \\
10 &6 &844427  \\
11 &9 &180078317 \\
12 &10 &1761702947 \\
13 &10 &8776320587 \\
14 &14 &27649987598537 \\
15 &15 &291598227841757 \\
16 &15 &521999251772081\,(?) \\
17 &?? &??\\
\,\vdots\\
21 &21 &234505015943235329417\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

where $\lceil x \rceil$ is the ceiling function. Assuming the *prime k-tuples conjecture* and Mollin's theorem 2.1 in *[Prime-Producing Quadratics](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~ramollin/PPQ.pdf)* (1997), this shows that the sequence is defined for $n>0$.

**Questions:**

1. Anyone has the resources to compute $A(16),\,A(17)$, etc?
2. It seems the second column has a comparable rate to the first. By the time it reaches $n=40$ (comparable to Euler's polynomial), what is a ballpark figure for $A$'s number of decimal digits? $40$? $50$?

Comment: The discriminant $d$ of the 8th polynomial, $m^2+m+21557$, is $d = -23^2\cdot 163$.

Comment: $A(16)\leq 521999251772081$ based on the [Mersenneforum post](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?s=1b573f91a849bbc8cfdf43892c18e342&p=164716).

Comment: @PeterKošinár: This is a good find! Thanks. Can you convert this to an answer?

Comment: Ok, my computer-powered verification confirmed that $A(16)$ is indeed equal to $521999251772081$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value $A(16)$ is equal to $521999251772081$:

- It is easy to check that it satisfies the given primality conditions.
- Minimality can be ascertained by exhaustively testing all smaller candidates; pre-sieving the possible residues modulo small primes reduces the range enough to allow exhaustive search to proceed successfully.

I will let the search run further and update the answer if any further values pop up eventually.

Comment: By the way, for $n>1$, all so far have $\lceil log_{10}A\rceil\leq n$, or the number of $A$'s decimal digits is $\leq n$.  Is there a heuristic to explain this?